# expand abbreviation with javascript in Codemirror/emmet

Tags: javascript, codemirror, emmet

I'am using codemirror and [emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror) for my project. expansion of emmet abbreviations works great in codemirror editor when done interactively (CTRL+E). I want to get a step further and create code by expanding abbreviations within JavaScript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/css/css.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resource/emmet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editorContainer"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var Test = {};
            Test.editor = null;

            Test.init = function() {
                Test.editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('editorContainer'), {
                    autofocus: true,
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    mode: "text/html",
                    profile: 'xhtml', /* define Emmet output profile */
                });
                emmetCodeMirror(Test.editor);
                Test.ol();
            }

            Test.ol = function() {
                Test.editor.getDoc().replaceSelection('ol>li*3', 'end');
                Test.editor.focus();
                emmetCodeMirror.emmet.run('expand_abbreviation', Test.editor);
            };

            Test.init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

by calling `Test.ol()` the text `ol>li*3` gets inserted but the following execution of

```
emmetCodeMirror.emmet.run('expand_abbreviation', Test.editor);
```

results in an `TypeError: editor.getProfileName is not a function emmet.js:41541`

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You can [download the project here](http://www.flashbrain.org/depot/problem.zip).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe there is an even more elegant solution by calling an emmet function and providing the abbreviation text as an argument instead of inserting the abbreviation text in the codemirror editor before calling an expand function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re passing `CodeMirror` editor instance to `emmet.run()` instead of `EmmetEditor`. Anyway, the ultimate solution is to simply exec registered Emmet command, e.g.

```
Test.editor.execCommand('emmet.expand_abbreviation')
```